# Need help on calculating difference between values in the column that match certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a table with the following columns:

- action
- articletype
- queueid
- status
- ticketid
- timestamp

I need to calculate for each row where articletype = "OUT" and action = "CREATE_ARTICLE" the difference between its timestamp value and previous timestamp value of the row where articletype = "IN" and action = "CREATE_ARTICLE" all in respect to the same ticket_id.

So I need to know how much time passed for each ticket from the point I received message (articletype = "IN") until the point I sent reply to it (articletype = "OUT"). The action = "CREATE_ARTICLE". The difference should be calculated between two consecutive timestamps.

Thank you!

[image: Table]

Comment: Your two problem statements contradict each another.  The first asks for `IN` - `OUT` while the second asks for `OUT` - `IN`.

Comment: Fixed, it's OUT - IN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window for `max()` with a filter on `articletype = 'IN'`:

```
select *, 
       case
         when articletype = 'OUT' 
           then timestamp 
             - max(timestamp) filter (where articletype = 'IN')
                 over (partition by ticketid
                           order by timestamp)
         else null
       end
  from table1
 where action = 'ARTICLE_CREATE'
   and articletype in ('IN', 'OUT');
```

The default unspecified record range for a window is `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`.

[Working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r6EW5qfzuRK6fe9PAskxRo/0) with only relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Use lead and lag to select next or prior rows. Here's some documentation and examples.

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/

Comment: I used lag but I don't know how to apply it to my case as I need to subtract particular values (out) from other particular values (in), so it needs conditional statement.

Comment: I see, in that case why not join from table where type is IN to table where type is OUT, then the IN and OUT times are in the same row.